# DropZone does not post $_FILES to form action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using DropZone JS which works perfectly on the frontend.

However I have been trying for hours, and have now simplified this example down to the point, that I simply cannot print_r my $_FILES uploaded from DropZone - where I am handling my form.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url('test-form'); ?>" class="dropzone" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And all I am doing where the form is submitted is running - print_r($_FILES);

When I add a file to input type file, obviously my array of the $_FILE is printed. But when I am submitting the form after having uploaded an image to the "DropZone", $_FILES is empty and my array prints  blank info.

What is wrong? Does someone know what's wrong here, any help is greatly appreciated! I have read many posts and scoured the internet for a solution but I cannot get anything to work.

Cheers!

Comment: It seems like you do not need a submit button in your form. Files seem to be uploaded directly upon being added to the dropzone.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a submit button in your form.

Files are uploaded (i.e. "submitted") directly upon being added to the dropzone, so just handle uploaded files as they arrive to your PHP script.

Comment: How do I handle the files if I am not using $_FILES? Also it's worth noting that I'm not only submitting files from dropzone, but data from text & select fields in my actual form.

Comment: When you drop a file in your dropzone, isn't your PHP script executed (and `$_FILES` correctly filled) ?